# Speed difference of CrystalDiskMark drive performance test for USB enclosure vs motherboard SATA connection - Normal or an issue?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, external-hard-drive, benchmarking, enclosures

I purchased a USB 3 SATA 2.5" drive enclosure, inserted a platter-based hard drive, and connected the enclosure to a USB 3.x port (if it's important, I can determine *x*).

Using CrystalDiskMark v8, the performance benchmarking values with the enclosure, with one exception, are close to the values returned when the drive was connected directly to the SATA connector on the laptop's motherboard.

The one exception, is the read speed for the `RND4K Q32T1` test (random reads of 4K with 32 queued at a time on 1 thread).  When connected to the motherboard's SATA connector, the speed was ~1.1MB/s.  When connected to the drive enclosure, the speed was exactly half that speed.

Is this an issue with the drive enclosure, or is this to be expected?

Comment: It is to be expected.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks. Do you know why?

Comment: SATA is the native connection; in an enclosure there's an USB-to-SATA converter. Even with the best controller and the best USB version and connection some bottleneck is to be expected. Modern adapters for USB3.x work almost as good as a direct SATA connection, the key word being "almost".